# Javascript/ HTML : elementFromPoint only ever returns HTMLBodyElement

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fire a click event on an element that is below a div that covers all content.

```
<div id='container'><div> 
  <div id='123'>
     <a href=''>Example link to activate</a>
  </div>
```

so I've written the following function, however this only ever returns "[object HTMLBodyElement]" in the function. Any ideas why elementFromPoint is not recognising the link element?

```
          function onDocumentClick( event ) {

              container.style.visibility = 'hidden';
              var ele = document.elementFromPoint(event.x, event.y);
              container.style.visibility = 'visible';
              alert(ele);
              document.removeEventListener('click', onDocumentClick, true);
              var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
              e.initEvent( 'click', true, true );                 
              document.addEventListener('click', onDocumentClick, true)
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time you're calling `elementFromPoint()`, the `#container` element and thus all his children are hidden. `elementFromPoint()` only sees visible nodes.

Please also note that `x` and `y` properties of `Event` object don't have good support in browsers. Better use `clientX`/`clientY`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I fail to understand how hiding the #container element effects the other children of the body element, considering that these other elements are not children of the #container element? These other elements are still visible.

Comment: @Dave Oh, I don't see any closing tag in your markup (isn't there a typo?) so I assumed `<a>` is child of `#container`... I'll have a look at it once again later. Anyway, live demo reproducing the issue would be helpful.